# Sonarqube not covering the import module

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

[image]

Sonarqube not covering the import statement and its impacting the total code coverage. Please guide if anyone faced such type of issue.

Comment: im facing the same issue. do you find a solution?